# Set password in a PDF generated with laravel barryvdh/laravel-snappy

Tags: php, laravel

guys, I need your support, I have to export a huge data in pdf format with password protection in package `barryvdh/laravel-snappy`.

I used `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` initially because it has `setEncryption()` method, but this package was not useful in generating large data because it is taking the large time and also making the system stuck/hang.

So I used laravel-snappy package, it is good with dealing with large data. But now the problem is that, it does not support `setEncryption()` method, so I am unable to password protect the generated pdf file.

I used https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk this package also with this code

```
                    $password_pdf = new Pdf($full_path_of_pdf);
                    $password_pdf->allow('AllFeatures')      // Change permissions
                        ->flatten()                 // Merge form data into document (doesn't work well with UTF-8!)
                        ->keepId('first')           // Keep first/last Id of combined files
                        ->dropXfa()                 // Drop newer XFA form from PDF
                        ->dropXmp()                 // Drop newer XMP data from PDF
                        ->needAppearances()         // Make clients create appearance for form fields
                        ->setPassword(123)          // Set owner password
                        ->setUserPassword(123)      // Set user password
                        ->passwordEncryption(128)   // Set password encryption strength
                        ->saveAs($new_full_path);
```

But nothing is happening, no new file is generating, the code is giving no errors anything.

So I want you guys to tell me is there any working method so that I can set password to my already existing pdf.

Comment: Did you find a solution to set a password with laravel-snappy?